# Cosmology - The Geodesic Equation Derivation

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, geodesics

My question relates to the derivation of the Geodesic Equation given on pages 121-122 of Baumann's [cosmology](http://physics.bu.edu/%7Eschmaltz/PY555/baumann_notes.pdf).

$$\frac{d^2x^i}{d\tau^2} = -\partial^i \Phi (dt/d\tau)^2 + O(\Phi^2). \tag{A.2.43}$$

On page 122, equation (A.2.43.) above involves a $(\Phi^2)$ term. It is not obvious to me where this extra term comes from. We have clearly made some approximations along the way, but why is the order $\Phi^2$? If someone could demonstrate with a mathematical expression where this comes from I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: There's quite a lot of questions here, it'd be easier if you focussed on just one.

Comment: Timelike curves are not endemic to cosmology, but GR as a whole - it simply means the (spacetime) trajectory carved out by a (massive) particle moving in spacetime (A massless particle carves a nulllike curve).

Comment: 'time-like curves' those which future-pointing and can describe massive real particles. "we could not have used ..." $\lambda$ is an affine parameter in general but any such parameter works, in the mentioned equation $\tau$ is selected specifically. And yes, proper time is the time measured by clocks traveling along time-like curves. So, clocks traveling along different curves click differently.  The last question is just saying that this is a lowest-order approximation, higher orders are not taking into account as in A.2.39.

Comment: @Eletie I am aware of that. I took the decision to combine them as one for the reason given in the first line of my post. They are linked by the same derivation. It would be much simpler to address them both in one post, rather than in two. I am entirely self-taught, so I would like to address both questions.

Comment: @NelsonVanegasA. I am aware of what the notation means, but why is the order term $\Phi^2$? Mathematically speaking, that is. What I am really after here is a demonstration with an expansion explicitly showing how the $\Phi^2$ arises.

Comment: @wrb98 but they are conceptually different questions (involving different calculations).

Comment: @G.Smith Didn't you comment on one of my previous posts that I shouldn't post images of the equations in question? I have provided a link, the author and the reference for this particular equation. I believe that to be sufficient for people to determine which equation I am discussing.

Comment: @Eletie They require different techniques, but are related. Many questions already on this site follow a similar line.

Comment: Then feel free to edit my question if it bothers you.

Comment: @G. Smith The original post has now been edited to accommodate your criticisms. Given the interest you have in this post, I look forward to seeing your solution.